# Preventing auto-filling of e-mail addresses on profile.php

Tags: users

This may be more of a web browser issue (Safari is my primary browser), but it's extremely irksome.

For some reason on one of my sites I'm developing whenever I edit a user account in profile.php it automatically loads my user account's name in the account e-mail field of whichever account I'm editing.  As it is not a valid e-mail address, this causes it to error, losing any changes unless I go back out to the user list and paste in their e-mail address.

I'm not sure why it would be auto-filling this field in the first place, much less with something so completely irrelevant.  Any ideas on what's up and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inject an `autocomplete` attribute into the form element on that page. There is a dedicated action for that: `user_edit_form_tag`.

```
add_action( 'user_edit_form_tag', function() {
    print ' autocomplete="off"';
});
```

If that doesn't help – and it looks like *the new IE* has a bug here – you could try the solution from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24207562/299509).

Here is some untested(!) code.  jQuery is always available on the page, so we don't have to take care of that. Note that I nested the callback registrations, because the constant `IS_PROFILE_PAGE` is only defined when the action `user_edit_form_tag` has been actually called.

```
add_action( 'user_edit_form_tag', function() {
    print ' autocomplete="off"';

    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817801/how-to-disable-auto-fill-in-safari-7
    $extra_action = IS_PROFILE_PAGE ? 'show_user_profile' : 'edit_user_profile';

    add_action( $extra_action, function() {
        ?>
<style>
.douchebag_safari {
    position: fixed;
    width: 1px;
    left: -5000px;
}
.douchebag_safari input {
    width: 1%;
}
</style>
<div class="douchebag_safari">
    <input class="js-clear_field" tabindex="-1" name="e-mail" type="email">
    <input class="js-clear_field" tabindex="-1" name="Ecom_User_Password" type="password">
</div>
        <?php

        add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', function() {
            ?>
<script>
    jQuery('#your-profile').on('submit', function () {
        "use strict";
        jQuery('.js-clear_field').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
</script>
            <?php

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: No luck with either, but once I've got the current batch of work out of the way I'll take a closer look at tweaking this.  Thanks for the suggestion!